# Google Code wiki

Tags: google-code

Is there a wiki engine that is similar to the one used on Google Code? I want to use that wiki with one of my websites.

Comment: You should as this at superuser.com

Comment: To run on which server platform?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/statwiki/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wikiwym**: http://code.google.com/p/wikiwym/
A JavaScript-based parser for the Google Code wiki syntax. Implemented in **JavaScript**.

**statwiki**: http://code.google.com/p/statwiki/
(Which Silas Sewell mentioned.)
A static wiki engine whose syntax is also the same as Google Code. Implemented in **python**.

I wish there was a Scala or Java implementation too.

Comment: google-code-wiki-to-html is not a parser! It is just a tool to download the wiki from Google code projects. AFAIK there is no parser for this markup in Java

Comment: @rmuller Okay, removed Java. Actually, I never added it: someone else edited this answer and added the Java program — the Java program's description is very very brief so I'm not surprised s/he was mistaken.  Anyway here's the link to the Java program: https://code.google.com/p/google-code-wiki-to-html/

Answer (score 0):

I think they developed it in house. You can host with them you know: http://code.google.com/hosting/

You could try Trac, which is what powers SourceForge: http://trac.edgewall.org/